# How do I set an audio file to certain characteristics?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, sox

How do I convert an mp3 file to a file with the following characteristics?

```
single-channel (monaural)
little-endian
unheadered
16-bit signed
PCM
sampled at 16000 Hz
```

I have tried running this command:

> ffmpeg -i audio16000.mp3 -ar 16000 -ac 1 audio16000.wav

When I checked the file with this command:

> sox --i audio16000.wav

I got the following results:

```
Input File     : 'audio16000.wav'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 16000
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:05:30.98 = 5295744 samples ~ 24823.8 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 10.6M
Bit Rate       : 256k
Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM
```

It doesn't say if it's little endian or if it's unheadered. I also thought only a raw file is unheadered, and that a wav file has a header, but instructions I'm reading tells me to use that ffmpeg command I used above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your goal is to convert to PCM (Pulse-Code Modulation), which is essentially a raw audio file. That's why you also need all the extra information about endianness, precision etc. There's no header that would tell you that, it's *unheadered*.

With your command, you converted the file instead to [WAVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) format, which by definition has a header defining the encoding.

What you meant is:

```
ffmpeg -i audio16000.mp3 -f s16le -ac 1 -ar 16000 audio16000.raw
```

- `-f s16le` - 16-bit little-endian
- `ac 1` - 1 channel
- `-ar 16000` - 16khz

What extension you use (PCM or RAW) is really up to you. When reading the file in, you will have to provide encoding yourself anyway.